# “Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at path $

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson, moshi

I have this method.

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
                    Type listMyData = Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Feed.class);
                    JsonAdapter<List<Feed>> adapter = moshi.adapter(listMyData);

                    List<Feed> feeds=adapter.fromJson(response);
                    EditText txtFeeds = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Feeds);
                    txtFeeds.setText(feeds.get(0).getFeeds_Header());
```

My JSON string is

```
`[{\"id\":\"877CB447-DC39-4AAD-8B40-A85F867C595A\",\"Feeds_Header\":\"Tentative Inter-se Seniority List of Tech. Asstt.\\\/ Progress Asstt.\\\/ Inspector (Statistics)\",\"Feeds_Date\":\"2019-01-16T00:00:00\"},{\"id\":\"F69213B9-A22D-4B0D-ABA4-14C3F5755766\",\"Feeds_Header\":\"Recruitment of 1 post of Vigyan Mandir Officer (VMO) on transfer from amongst Lecturers of Science\",\"Feeds_Date\":\"2019-01-11T00:00:00\"}]`
```

The JSON string is fetched from a WebAPI, I have tried in Gson, Jackson, and Moshi, but not able to resolve.

But when i declare a string variable and initialized it with the json string it works fine.

```
String json = "[{\"id\":\"877CB447-DC39-4AAD-8B40-A85F867C595A\",\"Feeds_Header\" ...
```

This is my Feed class

```
public class Feed {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @SerializedName("Feeds_Header")
    @Expose
    private String Feeds_Header;
    public String getFeeds_Header() {
        return Feeds_Header;
    }

    public void setFeeds_Header(String feedsHeader) {
        this.Feeds_Header = feedsHeader;
    }

    @SerializedName("Feeds_Date")
    @Expose
    private String Feeds_Date;
    public String getFeeds_Date() {
        return Feeds_Date;
    }

    public void setFeeds_Date(String feedsDate) {
        this.Feeds_Date = feedsDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: because the json you are getting has some invalid character such as "\" which is making it a bad json kindly check the Json structure in editor.

Comment: I have checked the json at https://jsonlint.com/ it says "valid json"

Comment: its not, the only reason its showing vaild json is because you are including " this at start and end which makes it a string, a json array starts with [ and a json object starts with {. Remove the inverted comma from start and end and it will show the reason of being an invalid json

Comment: I also thought of that, tried this code List<Feed> feeds=adapter.fromJson(response.substring(1,response.length()-1)); Throws the exception "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON  at path $[0]

Comment: check the json specification and remove invalid chars as mentioned in an earlier comment

Answer (score 0):

While doing parsing, you are parsing a string which is actually an array.
So confirm the response then make your POJO classes accordingly